# Downgrade mysql version macos

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, osx-yosemite

I have the following version of mysql : 5.7.19 but I need to downgrade it to 5.7.0 but I don't want to lose all my stored data. Is there any way to do this.

Mac version : OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Comment: have you read it? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/downgrading.html

Comment: @AlexanderMakarenko worst guide ever.